# {% block content %}{% endblock %} doesn't load/work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>NEW SEARCH</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

The template above doesn't work as it should.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? You should remove code from the title.

Comment: `{% extends %} ` is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
{% extends '<app_name>/base.html' %}
```

You forgot the `s` character when extending the template file.

Comment: @MuhammadRenzy I editted the answer, can you please put the app name you use to extend the template?

Comment: hay just fix it and it works fine. the problem was the urlspattern i put a wrong direction. my bad beginner mistakes. thank you @arthursribeiro appreciated your help